# Does exiting a login shell necessarily log out of the OS?

Tags: bash, logout

Bash manual says

> `logout [n]`
>
> Exit a login shell, returning a status of n to the shell’s parent.

On a virtual console of Ubuntu, I first log  in, and in the login shell, run:

```
$ pstree -paus $$
systemd,1 --system --deserialize 19
  `-login,30488 -p --  
      `-bash,31728,t
          `-pstree,31774 -paus 31728
```

and then run `logout`, and all the processes starting from `login,30488` till below disappear, more than just "return to the shell's parent" which is the`login` process.

In a login bash shell ,  does bash builtin command`logout` log out of the OS, not just exit the shell?

Does exiting a login shell (not necessarily by `logout`, but also any other way, such as bash builtin `exit` among others) necessarily lead to logging out of the OS?

May I also ask what logging out of OS means?

Thanks.

---

Extended to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887813/how-does-the-login-program-in-linux-invoke-a-login-shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` speak, "login shell" means a shell invoked with the `-l` flag, or where the first character of argument 0 begins with a `-`.  (See `man bash` INVOCATION section).

In your example, you can see process 31728 is called `-bash`, so begins with a `-` and so was invoked as a login shell.

`logout` simply exits a login shell.

So if you run `bash -l` and then `logout` you'll find yourself back at the calling shell.

```
$ echo $$
32145
$ bash -l
bash-4.2$ logout
$ echo $$
32145
```

Now the `login` program (process 30488 in your example) waits for the child shell to exit, then performs some cleanup actions (eg `wtmp`, `utmp`) then exits.  That is why you no longer see this process after running `logout`.